# How to set output parameter to a zip file in a custom geoprocessing function tool?

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing-service, geoprocessing-framework

I'm trying to write a custom geoprocessing function tool in ArcObjects that I can then expose as a service on ArcServer.  The output parameter will be a zip file that contains a filegeodatabase.  I have marked the parameter as a required and attempted to set some of the default properties of the GPDataFile class, but when I run my try task, no matter what I type into the "Output Export File" input box I get a message saying that it is required.

Does anybody have any samples on how to use and set the properties of the GPDataFile class to be used as an output parameter?

```cs
IGPDataFile gRDL = new GPDataFileClass();                
gRDL.DataType = "zip";
gRDL.DatasetName = "TableName";


IGPParameterEdit3 inputParameter = new GPParameterClass();
inputParameter.DataType = new GPDataFileTypeClass();

// Default Value object
inputParameter.Value = gRDL as IGPValue;

// Set Parameter properties
inputParameter.Direction = esriGPParameterDirection.esriGPParameterDirectionOutput;
inputParameter.DisplayName = "Output Export File";
inputParameter.Name = "out_export_file";
inputParameter.ParameterType = esriGPParameterType.esriGPParameterTypeRequired;
return inputParameter;
```

Comment: Have you tried using the DEFile Class instead?  It supports the IGPValue interface. This is designed for GP parameters. http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/DEFileClass_Class/001900000016000000/

Comment: Using the DEFileType over the GPDataFileTypeClass appears to work, but what is the difference between them?

Comment: That's a good question. I am not sure.  To me it seems like they should both work.  `DEFile` is from esriDataSources  so maybe it is better recognized as a data source.  On the other hand, `GPDataFile` is from Geoprocessing, which seems like it would be a better option to use for a tool parameter. Both support the `IGPValue` interface as well.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to chime in on this post because although the comments from [crmackey](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9899/crmackey) and [blawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/55884/blawson) helped to solve the original question, it was difficult putting the pieces together to get a file export to work on my own custom geoprocessor.

Here is what I used for defining the output parameter in the ParameterInfo property:

```
IGPParameterEdit3 outputParameter = new GPParameterClass();
outputParameter.DataType = new DEFileTypeClass();
outputParameter.Value = new DEFileClass();
outputParameter.Direction = esriGPParameterDirection.esriGPParameterDirectionOutput;
outputParameter.DisplayName = "Output File";
outputParameter.Name = "output_file";
outputParameter.ParameterType = esriGPParameterType.esriGPParameterTypeDerived;
parameters.Add(outputParameter);
```

and this is how I set the file within the Execute() method after creating a pdf file:

```
IGPParameter outputParameter = (IGPParameter)paramvalues.get_Element(3);
IGPValue value = new DEFileClass();
value.SetAsText(@"C:\output.pdf");
m_GPUtilities.PackGPValue(value, outputParameter);
```